# c# writing tag in audio file during playing. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, file-writing, taglib-sharp, wmplib

I made a c# player with WMPLib and TagLib.
My files are listed in a listview, i can click right on a row and in a popup add some tag (Year, rating...).
When the file is not playing, the tags can be saved in the file ( wav format) but not when playing.
Error : can't save because file in use.

i tryed to use async await but i don't know how it works in this case.
Here is the code to put 1 star as rating tag :

```
    private void t_star_1_Click2(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    if(listView1.Items != null){soundpath = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[8].Text;};
    var tagdusound = TagLib.File.Create(soundpath.ToString());
Tag tagg = tagdusound.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);
    PopularimeterFrame frame = PopularimeterFrame.Get((TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tagg, "Windows Media Player 9 Series", true);
        frame.Rating = 1;
        tagdusound.Save();PlaylistList_update();
        }//              Click droit ★
```

Comment: the other process has a lock on it. you likely can't save it w/o closing that lock

Comment: You could built a list of files to update later, and then do it at shutdown or startup.